# Proof from equality

Tags: real-numbers

suppose this equality holds:

x, y, z are real

15(x + y + z) = 12(xy + yz + xz) = 10(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )

and at least one variables isn't zero.

I need to proof that x + y + z = 4 and find the smallest posible closed interval [a,b] in which are all possible solutions for x, y, z.

I have tried several approaches, but all of them went to some non-sense.

Thanks.

P.S. For some strange reason I can't add the greeting to the beginning of this post, so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Using the identity

$$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz$$

and the given equalities you have

$$(x+y+z)^2=\frac{15}{10}(x+y+z)+\frac{15}{6}(x+y+z).$$

Could you continue from this point?

Comment: Cool, that helped with x + y + z = 4 problem, but what about the interval?
Now I know these: x+y+z = 4, xy + yz + xz = 5, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6.

Comment: $x+y+z=4$ is a plane and $x^2+y^2+z^2=6$ is a sphere. The intersection is a circumference. Could you get the center and the radius? Maybe this link http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Spher/SpherePlaneIntersection_.htm could be useful.

Comment: I can solve it using your link or WolframAlpha, but isn't there a simplier way?

Comment: With your particular data you could try to find a center of the form $(a,a,a)$ to get $a=0.$ But, at this moment, I don't know a way to get the answer more quickly.

Comment: I asked the same question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/2jpjty/proof_from_equality) and some reditor is helping me out as well, so maybe you could look there…

Comment: Are you allowed to use Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I have no idea what that is…